# Add data in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    setState(state + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify([state].push(state)));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I try to add in `localStorage` numbers clicking on the button.
At the end i want to get in local storage something like this: [1,2,3,4,5,6], depending how many times user click on button.

 Now i don't get the expected value.

 Question: How to get what i described?
demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-grothendieck-dwewm?file=/src/App.js:0-359

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, could you show a solution?

Comment: You need an array instead of a number for `state`. However if all you want is a count why would you need an array in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try getting current stored values from localStorage, push the new state and then set in localStorage with updated array. (First time when value not available in LS, default the value to []).

```
export default function App2() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const add = () => {
    const newState = state + 1;
    setState(newState);
    // Get the currently stored clicks from local storage
    const clicks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data2")) ?? [];
    clicks.push(newState);
    localStorage.setItem("data2", JSON.stringify(clicks));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>click2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const add = () => {
     const _numbers = [...state];
     _numbers.push(_numbers.length + 1);
     setState(_numbers);
     localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(_numbers));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. it clones *(not nested objects, beware!)* the empty array (state)
2. it adds to the array, the length of the array + 1, so you get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc..
3. it sets the state with that value and stringifies that value to localstorage

other possibility with prevState in a setState call, does basically the same but uses a reference variable

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

const add = () => {
  setState(prevState => {
    prevState.push(prevState.length + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(prevState));
    return prevState;
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you still need `_numbers` if you use state function updater like I did in my answer. I don't know, I am asking it for my own knowledge?

Comment: Ok, just tested.. yes it is not in sync.

Comment: @ArupRakshit What is not in sync, my answer or your answer? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Ok, glad I could help! there is another possibility, I will add it to my answer

Comment: I updated my answer.. :) But it now mostly looks like yours with little difference.

Comment: This async thing in React very easily get missed when you are not using it everyday.. It creates tricky bug in code.

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes, indeed.. I updated my answer, you might find it interesting :-)

Comment: Same as me.. :) But why did you use `push`? shouldn't it be `concat`? push returns length of the original array after mutation.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh, darn, didn't even notice good you say it!

Answer (score 0):

First: your state should be `const [state, setState] = useState([]);`

Second:
[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called. You want [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method is used to merge two or more arrays returns the new constructed Array.

So this should work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const add = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.concat(prevState.length + 1);
      localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(newState));
      return newState;
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: bear in mind that setState is asynchronous, so this means that localstorage gets the value of the older version of the state.

Comment: Ah, I see you got the exact same solution as my second, didn't even notice haha, good job!